# SQL SUM until condition

Tags: sql, sum, subquery, window-functions

I have a table `itineraire` that have 4 colums, `order`, `id_arret`, `nom`, `temp_moyen` .

[image]

so i want to **SUM** the `temp_moyen` until the `id_arret` = X and stops

*exemple:*

if `id_arret`=5 the SUM sould be : 0+5+4+3+6= **18**

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `where` clause to filter the values you want:

```
select sum(temp_moyen)
from t
where id_arret < ?;
```

If you wanted a *different* column for the stops, say `nom`, then you can use a subquery:

```
select sum(temp_moyen)
from t
where t.order < (select t2.order from t t2 where t2.id_arret = ?);
```

Comment: the `id_arret` is not ordred, it can be 5,10,2,9,3 ...

Comment: First, it is ordered in your sample data.  Second, *something* has to specify the ordering.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Oh, I see you have such a column, so I modified the second example to show you how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you want:

```
select sum(temp_moyen)
from mytable t
where t.ord <= (select t1.ord from mytable t1 where t1.id_arret = 5)
```

This identifies the `ord` that corresponds to `id_arret` `5`, and then sums its `temp_moyen` with all preceding rows.

You can also use window functions:

```
select sum_temp_moyen
from (
    select t.*, sum(temp_moyen) over(order by ord) sum_temp_moyen
    from mytable t
) t
where id_arret = 5
```

I renamed `order` to `ord`, because the former is a reserved in virtually all datatabases (as in `order by`).